# How can I swap contents of two text files with kernel system calls

Tags: c, kernel, system-calls

Here is my poor attempt:

```
//open:
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
//raad, write, exit:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//renameat2:
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
        int fd1, fd2;
        //do I need those ifs?
        if((fd1 = open("foo", O_RDWR)) == -1){
            write(2, "File failed to open in read/write mode\n", 33);
            exit(-1);
        }

        if((fd2 = open("bar", O_RDWR)) == -1 ){
            write(2, "File failed to open in read/write mode\n", 34);
            exit(-1);
        }

        renameat2(AT_FDCWD,fd1,AT_FDCWD,fd2, RENAME_EXCHANGE);

        close(fd1);
        close(fd2);
        exit(0);
}
```

I'm trying to use the system call function "renameat2", but it gives me errors:

main.c:24:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'renameat2'; did you mean 'rename'?

main.c:24:13: error: 'AT_FDCWD' undeclared (first use in this function)

main.c:24:40: error: 'RENAME_EXCHANGE' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: Does adding `#define _GNU_SOURCE` at the very top, above all the `#include`s, fix it?

Comment: Yes, it helped. But it recursively opens two more more questions: Why it helped, and now how to deal with: main.c:22:28: warning: passing argument 2 of 'renameat2' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Comment: OK I got it. I found the mistake and edited it. Now, why does this helped? #define _GNU_SOURCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

First, since `renameat2` isn't part of any standard, you need to `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before you include any header files to use it. See [`man 7 feature_test_macros`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) for a longer explanation of this.

Second, `renameat2` doesn't support `AT_EMPTY_PATH` like other syscalls do (and even if it did, that's not how you'd use it), so you need to pass it the names of the files you want to rename, not FDs. It follows from this that you don't need to open the files.

Here's your code with both of those things fixed:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        renameat2(AT_FDCWD,"foo",AT_FDCWD,"bar", RENAME_EXCHANGE);

        exit(0);
}
```

And here's a more flexible version with better error handling:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 3) {
        fputs("Wrong number of arguments\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    if(renameat2(AT_FDCWD, argv[1], AT_FDCWD, argv[2], RENAME_EXCHANGE)) {
        perror("renameat2");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: maybe it would be better: exit(renameat2(AT_FDCWD,"foo",AT_FDCWD,"bar", RENAME_EXCHANGE));    ?

Comment: Yes, but put a negative sign in front of `renameat2`, because if it fails, it returns `-1`, but your process should return `1`. It also might be worth actually using an `if` statement so you can use `perror` to say why it failed.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it, please? And thank you for the answers.